# Auto save form field inputs using jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

I have a form with different input fields.So for very minute , the data entered by the user needs to be automatically stored in the database. Once the request is submitted , it will be directed to the struts file where the database interactions will be carried out .

What i have tried, I had set the timeout function to run every time the page is loaded

```
var timer;
$(document).ready(function() {
timer = setTimeout("autosave()", 60000); 
});
```

And in the autosave function , i am trying to post the input data to the designated URL

```
jQuery('form').each(function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:7002/submitStudent.do?requestType=auto&autosave=true",
            data: jQuery(this).serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data){
                if(data && data == 'success') {
                    alert("data saved");
                }else{
                }
            }
        }); 
    }); 
}
 }
```

And once the request is sent to the struts , it will be processed based on the requesttype and the data will be submitted.

But in my case , data doesn't get saved.

Kindly share your suggestions on what i am doing wrong and any other ways to do it ?

Thanks for your valuable suggestion and time..

FYI , i am a beginner in Jquery and ajax technologies

JSFIDDLE : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jegadeesb/o0c3rmp3/1/)

Comment: Is the data getting saved in you database?

Comment: `requestType="auto"` write this without double quotes..

Comment: `setTimeout ` will not call every minute .

Comment: Something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o0c3rmp3/3/) should do what is required. 6 seconds instead of 60 is for testing.

Comment: @Kushal No the data is not saved

Comment: @Regent Thanks for the edited fiddle .But am i doing it correct in the URL?

Comment: @jegadees what is the problem with URL? You have specified `http://localhost:7002/submitStudent.do?requestType=auto&autosave=true` which is valid URL, and form data is sent being serialized inside POST body. Whether you handle it correctly on server side or not - I don't know.

Comment: When you deploy it to server, the URL will be changed. So what I suggest is do not mention `localhost` in URL..

Comment: @jegadees you're welcome. You can use some debugging tools to see how actually data is sent. Then you will be able to handle it on server-side.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Modified it.Thanks

Comment: Anytime buddy.. Happy coding.. :)

Comment: @ HI All ,The setInterval doesn't seems to be triggering for my case.The page is static

Answer (score 3):

I have made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o0c3rmp3/5/) according to your requirement.

```
var timer;

var fun = function autosave() {
    alert();
    jQuery('form').each(function () {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:7002/submitStudent.do?autosave=true",
            data: jQuery(this).serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                if (data && data == 'success') {
                    alert("data saved");
                } else {}
            }
        });
    });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(fun, 1000);
    //setInterval(fun,1000);
});
```

You need to focus on two methods `setTimeout` and `setInterval`. setTimeout will call `autosave()` after 1 second of DOM loading but only once. `setInterval` will call `autosave()` after every 1 second repeatedly. You can read it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp).

> The `setTimeout()` method calls a function or evaluates an expression
>   after a specified number of milliseconds. **Tip: The function is only executed once. If you need to repeat execution, use the `setInterval()` method.**

For more details on your ajax request you need to look at the console(F12) errors.

Comment: This approach will work only for scenarios where there are not so many ajax  calls fired in small period of time. For example, when running automatic UI tests in parallel, this will NOT work.. Also better use `debounce` than `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use [ajaxForm](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#api) plugin

and in the autosave function just fire $('form').submit();

this is the fast and good way

Comment: So, instead of pointing out that `setTimeout` runs once, and `setInterval` is more suitable there, you just suggest plugin for form submitting?

Comment: @Moayad AL-Najdawi , Thanks for your reply.But i am planning to do it without a plugin

Comment: i assumed you will  call autosave  function another time inside it  then you will fire the autosave every 6 Second

Comment: @jegadees oh sorry i saw in your tags jquery-plugins so i put  a plugin to help you